# Django : possible to override Admin sort action?

Tags: django, django-admin

I feel like this should be possible but I can't work out how.

I have a model :

```
class ModelClass (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

Within a Django Admin list screen is there any way to, when the user clicks on the top of the 'name' column to sort on the 'nickname' values ?

I feel like there should be a means of intercepting the processing which would otherwise cause the resultset to be resorted in response to the click on the column top and then do that sortation in the way I would like to do it before allowing the list screen to be redrawn .

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can output the `name` in the list using the ModelAdmin's method with the defined `admin_order_field` property:

```
class ModelClassAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('get_name', 'email')

    def get_name(self, obj):
        return obj.name
    get_name.short_description = 'name'
    get_name.admin_order_field = 'nickname'
```

Comment: Thanks very much and sorry for the slow reply. I had read the docs for this but I hadn't realised they could be interpreted in this way.